# Convert dataframe values based on column and index name and original value

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a following data frame

```
                                  MX AX3 AX5  AX7 AX7L
Feature                                               
ADAS-Lane Departure Warning       No  No  No  Yes  Yes
ADAS - Adaptive Cruise Control**  No  No  No  Yes  Yes
ADAS - High Beam Assist           No  No  No  Yes  Yes
ADAS - Traffic Sign Recognition   No  No  No  Yes  Yes
360 Surround View System          No  No  No   No  Yes
```

with **columns** : MX AX3 AX5  AX7 AX7L

and

**index** : ADAS-Lane Departure Warning , ADAS - Adaptive Cruise Control**, ADAS - High Beam Assist, ADAS - Traffic Sign Recognition, 360 Surround View System.

I want to convert the value '**No**' in df to {corresponding index} is not present in {corresponding column name}

and

value '**Yes**' to {corresponding index} is present in {corresponding column name}

I tried the following thing:

```
# define the function to apply to each element
def convert_value(value, index, column):
    if value == 'Yes':
        return f'{index} is present in {column} variant'
    else:
        return f'{index} is not present in {column} variant'


# apply the function to each element of the DataFrame
df = df.applymap(lambda x: convert_value(x, df.index, df.columns))
```

but I am not getting the desired results thus please help me convert it to desired values.

Comment: What's the expected output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can create a function called `convert_value` and apply it row-wise using the argument `axis=1`. Note that when we use `df.apply(lambda row: convert_value(row), axis=1)`, row will be read into `convert_value` as a `pd.Series` where `row.index` will be the column names, and `row.name` will be the name of corresponding index.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'MX':["No"]*5,'AX3':['No']*5,'AX7':['Yes']*4+['No']}, index=['ADAS-Lane Departure Warning','ADAS 2','ADAS 3', 'ADAS 4', '360 Surround'])
columns = df.columns

def convert_value(row):
    cols = list(row.index)
    index = row.name
    values = row.values
    return pd.Series([
        f'{index} is present in {col} variant' if val == "Yes" 
        else f'{index} is not present in {col} variant' 
        for col,val in zip(cols, values)
    ])

df = df.apply(lambda row: convert_value(row), axis=1)
df.columns = columns
```